# MDX constrained strtoset() with item list

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, data-cube

We're developing a SSRS report using MDX. We need to filter by a list of items. We have a multiple items parameter based on a dataset lookup for our 'Intake' dimension. We've followed an MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx) about how to use a list as a filter parameter. We ended up writing the following parameter function:

```
="{[Student Application].[Intake].[" + Join(Parameters!IntakeList.Value,"],[Student Application].[Intake].[")+"]}"
```

This generates a parameter, passed to the constrained STRTOSET by SSRS' query designer, like so:

```
{[Student Application].[Intake].[Apr 2011],[Student Application].[Intake].[Apr 2012]}
```

When we run the report SSRS returns the following MDX error:

```
The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function were violated.
```

Yet it seems to follow the correct syntax defined by the MSDN article. Any help appreciated!

Comment: you've confirmed that those two items exist in the SSAS database: [Student Application].[Intake].[Apr 2011] and [Student Application].[Intake].[Apr 2012] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into this Post [Assign multi-values parameter to MDX query report](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/10/passing-multi-value-tsql-parameter-to.html)

Do no use **CONSTRAINED** keyword while using **StrToSet(Set_Specification [,CONSTRAINED] )**

Comment: Unfortunately this means that you can't use Query Generator and have to modify the query manually, but it is the only answer.